# Moving EF Migrations folder to a separate project

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So I've been using EF Migrations (EF 6.3) for just over a month now and the assembly "bloat" resulting from each migration is already pretty noticeable (almost 3 MB).

I'd like to move the migrations folder to a separate project, and have attempted this using the following command:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Blah.Data.Migrations -ContextProjectName Blah.Data -ContextTypeName Blah.Data.Context.BlahContext -StartUpProjectName Blah.Web.Portal
```

This then creates a new Configuration in the Blah.Data.Migrations project, which then needs a reference back to the project containing the context (Blah.Data).

So far, so good. My problem is that the context contains an initializer that requires a reference to the Configuration, which is now in the Blah.Data.Migrations project; obviously this can't have a reference back to the Blah.Data.Migrations project, as that would result in a circular reference.

```
namespace Blah.Data.Context
{
  [DbConfigurationType(typeof(BlahDbConfiguration))]
  public class BlahContext : DbContext, IDbContext
  {
      public BlahContext() : base("BlahContext")
      {
          Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlahContext, Configuration>());
      }
  }
}
```

Is this achievable using Enable-Migrations? If not, is there another ( preferably non-hacky :) ) way of moving the existing migrations into a separate project?

Comment: I am not sure but `Configuration` class is by default internal and sealed. `Database.SetInitializer()` you can use f.e. in your `global.asax.cs` file.

Comment: Have you considered just consolidating your legacy migrations? http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Comment: FYI I'm using Owin (the front-end is an AngularJS app), and the web site has no reference to EF, System.Data etc - everything is separated into layers. Also calling Database.SetInitializer would still require a reference to the Configuration class (circular).

Comment: Also FYI - this isn't about legacy migrations - I'm thinking about the bloat resulting from incremental changes moving forward. We can't consolidate/archive existing migrations as that would effect any/all existing databases (would have to manually "fix up" the existing migrations in each and every __MigrationHistory table).